# Usefulness of using properties for IBOutlets under ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Under ARC, what's the point of making every IBOutlet a property? What would be the downside of using ivars for IBOutlets used only internally by the view controller?

Comment: Why do you think that one have to create properties?

Comment: @Phlibbo: I keep seeing here and there that it's "good practice" and simplifies viewDidUnload code.

Comment: I wish there was an "Effective iOS" book similar to the ones written by Scott Meyers and Herb Sutter for C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't use the setter/getter methods for anything, don't rely on key-value observing for those properties, and don't anticipate that a subclass would benefit from overriding those properties, then there's no real downside to just using ivars for IBOutlets under ARC.

Comment: Thanks, ivars will eliminate a lot of `self.` prefixes in my code.

Comment: Please check out my answer and let me know if you have any insights into what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using ivars for my "private" IBOutlets and ran into memory leak problems. I think it's because my IBOutlets used the `__unsafe_unretained` attribute instead of `__weak`. I can't use `__weak` because it's not supported on iOS 4 (I want my app to be backwards compatible with iOS 4). It's difficult to grasp what's really happening with ARC, IBOutlets, viewDidUnload, and all that mess. Sigh...

Anyways, when I changed my IBOutlets from ivars to properties, the memory leak issues went away.

So, to answer my own question, one downside of using ivars for IBOutlets is that you might run into memory leaks if you have the `__unsafe_unretained` attribute.

Comment: It's unlikely that this was the source of your leaks. If your outlets were `__unsafe_unretained`, then by definition those ivars were not retaining their targets, and *not retaining* something can never cause a leak. (It could cause a crash, but that's another story.) You didn't specify whether the properties you added were likewise `unsafe_unretained`, but either way, the only thing you could have done by adding properties is cause *more* retaining. Without more details, it's impossible to say why you were leaking. You could submit another question if you're really curious.

Comment: The properties I added were indeed `unsafe_unretained`. I'm really puzzled as to why changing IBOutlets from ivars to properties made a difference. Maybe I'm not interpreting XCode's Instruments correctly.

Comment: unsafe_unretained may cause a crash, but it won't cause a leak. I'd say you're interpreting Instruments wrong. Sorry. :) But that said, it's been many months now: Do you have any extra insight into what was happening?

Comment: I've moved on to iOS 5 (dropped support for iOS 4.x) so I don't use `unsafe_unretained` anymore. I haven't tried changing my `IBOutlet` properties back to ivars, so I don't know if the original problem is still there.

Comment: We had the exact same problem. We had IBOutlets as ivars with unsafe_unretained and we had a memory leak that would eventually cause the app to crash. If we targeted iOS 5 and changed them to weak it was fine. We ended up moving them to properties with unsafe_unretained and its fine now.